# JQuery - Document width/height - Different values from different browsers

Tags: jquery

```
var maskWidth = $(window).width();
alert(maskWidth);
```

I get 1263 from chrome and firefox (which is 1280 in fact, but with scroll it write a less value). IE print 1259.

How can I fix this problems with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.clientCoords = function(){
    if(jQuery.browser.msie){
        return {
            w:document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
            h:document.documentElement.offsetHeight
        }
    }
    else
        return {w:window.innerWidth, h:window.innerHeight}
}
```

**This function returns the height and weight of browser or current window**

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a problem with jQuery, it is returning the value of the displayable portion of your website.

You need to be looking at `.innerWidth()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) which will return results closer to which you require.

Comment: Thanks. But : `This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead.`